# Parameter undefined in method of an object

Tags: javascript, next.js

I can't seem to add a parameter to my function in my object. My object needs to receive outside information from my function but it's telling me that the parameter is undefined.

This is the object

```
const data = {
  labels: GenerateAllQuantities(QuantityPerOrder)
}
```

And the function is:

```
function GenerateAllQuantities(QuantityPerOrder) {
    var TotalQuantityPerAmmount = [QuantityPerOrder];
    var AmmountsOfOrder = QuantityPerOrder / 8;

    for(var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        let OrderQuantity = TotalQuantityPerAmmount[0] - AmmountsOfOrder;
        TotalQuantityPerAmmount.unshift(OrderQuantity)
    }

    return TotalQuantityPerAmmount;
}
```

When I write directly:

```
const data = {
  labels: GenerateAllQuantities(80)
```

I get my answer directly, the issue is the parameter.

Comment: you have a typograhical error here `labels: GenerateAllQuantitiest(80)`. It should be `GenerateAllQuantities`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
const data = {
  labels: GenerateAllQuantities
}
```

Then when you want to use it (in this example, with a parameter of 60), you will invoke the function by doing the following:

```
let myFunctionReturn = data.labels(60)
```

If you always want your parameter to be 80, then have your object's `labels` key point to an invoked function with 80 wrapped by a non-invoked anonymous pointer function:

```
const data = {
  labels: () => GenerateAllQuantitiest(80)
}
```

This will ensure that when your labels function does run, it runs with the parameter `80`.

To run the "always 80" version of your function, do the following:

```
let myFunctionReturn = data.labels()
```

In your code when you had

```
const data = {
  labels: GenerateAllQuantitiest(80)
}
```

the function ran immediately, and then `data.labels` was no longer a function, but turned into whatever the return of your function was.